# Ruby on Rails undefined method `attr_accessible' and 'before_save'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I recently started a new RoR project, and copied some of my old code from about 6 months ago.

For some reason, I'm getting the following error in my User model:

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for User:Class
```

When I comment the attr_accessible line out, I then get a similar error in the same file:

```
undefined method `before_save' for User:Class
```

And when I comment that out, I get another one:

```
undefined method `validates' for User:Class
```

Why would attr_accessible and before_save be undefined methods?  I thought those were built in to Ruby on Rails!?

Comment: Can you post the User class? Is it definitely inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add  < ActiveRecord::Base (I had been experimenting with using a different db)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your User class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base?

It should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```