# Undefined Method attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am somewhat new to rails and I am trying to create a User login.  I went through the tutorial found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/).  At the end it had me add "attr_accessible" for mass assignment.  However when I did that I got the following error:

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x007ff70f276010>
```

I saw on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273812/ruby-on-rails-undefined-method-attr-accessible-and-before-save) that I neeed < ActiveRecord::Base.  But I do have that included.  Here is the code for my User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end

end
```

Any other ideas on what could be causing this problem would be really appreciated, thanks!

Edit:  On Rails 4.1.  Looks like it doesn't apply anymore.  Thanks fotanus

Comment: [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371334/how-is-attr-accessible-used-in-rails-4). Fix your question with the correct rails version you are using, since it is important for this question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

No mass assignment allowed for Rails 4.1

instead of having `attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation` in your model, use [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). 
You'll do this in your UsersController:

```
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

then call the user_params method in your controller actions.

Answer (score 18):

No mass assignment allowed for Rails 4.1

You will have to try something like this.

```
class Person
  has_many :pets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
end

class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

  ...

  private

    def person_params
      # It's mandatory to specify the nested attributes that should be whitelisted.
      # If you use `permit` with just the key that points to the nested attributes hash,
      # it will return an empty hash.
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, pets_attributes: [ :name, :category ])
    end
end
```

Refer

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are installed gem *protected_attributes* (or *protected_attributes_continued* in case Rails 5+) that this gem is present in your gemfile and run `bundle install` terminal.  Then restart your server.

Comment: There is a new gem for the new rails versions:
- protected_attributes_continued