# Saving attributes fields in devise User model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I just followed [this](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/) guide to add the columns 'firstname' and 'secondname' to the Devise User Model with the following commands.

```
rails generate migration add_firstname_to_user firstname:string
rails generate migration add_secondname_to_user secondname:string
```

and I aplied the changes with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

It worked ok, because I can see those fields in the console with User.all, but the problem I have now is that I don't see the attr_accessible field in app/model/user.rb.

So I just added the lines:

```
<div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :second_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :secondname, autofocus: true %></div>
```

in new.html.erb in app/views/devise/registrations, but it isn't working, because I noticed that the firstname and secondname attributes are nil on the users I registered.

What can I do?, I guess is something about the attr_accessible step, but I couldn't find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused by your post, but I believe (as mentioned in step 3 of your linked document) you need to add the following to your user.rb:

```
attr_accessible :firstname, :secondname
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe I don't express very good, english is not my first language, but responding your comment... if I add attr_accessible :firstname, :secondname in my user.rb I got an error that says: "undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x007fd0dc554678>", when I try to enter to the "Sign Up" page...

Comment: Yes, no mass assignment allowed in Rails 4.1.  Use the permit method in your controller - see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437830/undefined-method-attr-accessible

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure permitted parameters for devise. In 
*app/controllers/application_controller.rb* add the following lines:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :secondname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :secondname ,:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

See that you can add multiple columns (fields) in one migration:

`rails g migration add_fields_to_user firstname:string secondname:string`

This will generate a file inside:

`db/migrate/20152347823846(just numbers here)_add_fields_to_user.rb`

and you also can edit that file to add fields and then run `rake db:migrate`.

I know it's late to respond, but better late than never.