# Paperclip Issue - can't update and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

**CONTROLLER**

CREATE

```
  def create
    set_cache_buster
    @court_agency = CourtAgency.new(court_agency_params)
    @court_agency.created_by = current_user
    @court_agency.updated_by = current_user
    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @court_agency.save
        flash[:success] = 'Court was successfully created.'
        format.html do
          redirect_to court_agencies_path
        end
        format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{court_agencies_path}'" }
      else
        format.json { render json: @court_agency.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

UPDATE

```
  def update
    set_cache_buster
    @court_agency = CourtAgency.find(params[:id])
    @court_agency.updated_by = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @court_agency.update_attributes(court_agency_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Court was successfully updated.'
        format.html do
          redirect_to court_agencies_path
        end
        format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{court_agencies_path}'" }
      else
        format.json { render json: @court_agency.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

STRONG PARAMETER

```
  def court_agency_params
    params.require(:court_agency).permit(
      :type,
      :subtype,
      :division,
      :associate_justice,
      :presiding_justice,
      :map,
      :landmark_image,
      ]
    ) if params[:court_agency]
  end
```

**MY VIEW**

```
= form_for(@court_agency, remote: true, html: { :multipart => true, class: 'form-horizontal ajax-form', style: 'margin-bottom: 0;', 'data-model-name' => 'court_agency'}) do |f|
    .form-group
      = f.label :landmark_image, 'Landmark', class: 'control-label'
      %br/
      = f.file_field :landmark_image, class: 'btn btn-warning'
      - if @court_agency.map.present?
        = image_tag @court_agency.map.url(:small), class: 'img-responsive img-thumbnail'
    .form-group
      = f.label :map, 'Map', class: 'control-label'
      %br/
      = f.file_field :map, class: 'btn btn-warning'
      - if @court_agency.map.present?
        = image_tag @court_agency.map.url(:small), class: 'img-responsive img-thumbnail'
```

**MODEL**

```
  #Paperclip
  has_attached_file :map,
                    :styles => { :large => "900x900>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "196x196>", :small => '50x50>' },
                    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png'),
                    :url => "/assets/court_agencies/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/court_agencies/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :map, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  has_attached_file :landmark_image,
                    :styles => { :large => "900x900>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "196x196>", :small => '50x50>' },
                    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png'),
                    :url => "/assets/court_agencies/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/court_agencies/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :landmark_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Ok here's the problem:

When I create without file upload, it works. But when I attach file, params not working and it leaves blank. So when I binding.pry:

```
[1] pry(#<CourtAgenciesController>)> params
=> {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"court_agencies"}
```

Params is missing.

---

When I update without file upload, it works. But when I attach file, the error is:

```
Started POST "/court_agencies/53" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-08 16:03:21 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/court_agencies/53"):
```

or just like

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/court_agencies/53"
```

on browser.

I have remotipart installed.
Also Paperclip.

Please help. Need it badly.

**UPDATE:**

---

ROUTES:

```
  #COURT AGENCY
  resources :court_agencies do
    member do
      get 'list'
      put 'update_uin'
    end
    collection do
      get 'get_court_agency_list'
      get 'court_agency_list'
      get 'add'
      get 'get_uin'
    end
  end
```

This issue is about `remote: true`. How is it possible to create/update submitting via ajax with file upload?

Comment: Can you add the routes, its qurious not sure why a route that was working before is not working now.

Answer (score 0):

do you have defined [attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) in your model...i didnt see that in your model

```
attr_accessible: :type,:subtype,:division,:associate_justice,:presiding_justice,:map,:landmark_image,
```

Comment: based here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437830/undefined-method-attr-accessible, we use strong parameters instead of attr_accessible. My version of Rails is 4.1.5

Comment: sorry i missed it... @BartSabayton..what do you get at the server log..can you post it too..you should get something like "court_agency"=>{ "landmark_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa7f83cb778 @original_filename="image_1", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition:....