# Rails: Generate a link and save it to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside a loop in my views I have the following code, that combines a few variables for each record:

```
<% $theurl = newbrandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=sales" %>

<%= link_to $theurl, class: "btn btn-success" do %>
 Order
<% end %>
```

But that's only in my views. What I want to do is to get this done outside of my views after an Order get's saved to the DB and save the link to the DB. Is that possible?

Edit:

My Model:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :url
after_create :save_link

 def save_link
  brandurl = Brand.where(:company => @sale.brand).pluck(:url)
  newbrandurl = brandurl.shift.strip
  unique_id = [@sale.token, @sale.created_at.strftime('%d%m%y-%H:%M:%SUTC')].join("&")
  self.save_link = newbrandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=sales"
 end
end
```

Comment: Active record callbacks, will help you with that. you can use `:before_save` callback for your Order model to call a method, which can generate and save this URL

Comment: How would I implement the code mentioned above in a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a :after_create callback

```
Class ModelName < ActiveXXX
    attr_accessible :url # the attribute name for storing the link
    after_create :save_link

    def save_link
        self.save_link = newbrandurl + "/?utm_campaign=" + unique_id + "&utm_source=sales"
    end
end
```

you will however, need to add the object data(newbrandurl, unique_id), however relevant if its coming from some other source

Comment: I edited my answer. Now I get a 'undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x007fa8d131afc0>' error.

Comment: Ah.. I got it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23437995/5243191

Now I get a 'undefined method `brand' for nil:NilClass' error for this line 'brandurl = Brand.where(:company => @sale.brand).pluck(:url)'

Comment: what is @sale ? here it should be `self`