# gem google cloud messaging for rails browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging

when i'm following this guide [gcm_on_rails](https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails), i get some error

when i try execute 'rails generate gcm_migrations' on my console, i get error like below :

```
while trying to load the gem 'gcm_on_rails'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x0000000121c298>
Did you mean?  attr_accessor
```

how to fix it?
i'm trying to implements google cloud messaging on browser

need help

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in [A Guide for Upgrading Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html):

> Rails 4.0 has removed `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected` feature in favor of Strong Parameters.

So if you're into Rails 4.0, you can use [Protected Attributes gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) for a smooth upgrade path or you can also do what was suggested in this related SO post - [Undefined Method attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437830/undefined-method-attr-accessible) by using strong parameters.

I hope those given options work for you.